# Could the Immune Gene HLA-B27 be gentically altered, snipped, switched off, replaced, edited within the body

Tags: genetics, immunology

Could the Immune Gene HLA-B27 be genetically altered, snipped, switched off, replaced, edited within the body.?

Thousands upon thousands suffer immune disease as do I from this highly implicated gene.

Is their a gene manipulation mechanism that 'could' work for this gene from within the body ?